# Display "marked as final" status for a document in SharePoint Online document library view

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document, spfx-extensions, modern-document-library

There is a feature inside Word, Excel and PowerPoint to mark a document as final. More info here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/help-prevent-changes-to-a-final-version-of-a-file-b1af610f-f172-42c9-85fc-a178a503cc81?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

[image]

Basically you go inside the Office Document go to File > Protect Document > Mark as Final. The next time someone opens that document a message appears at the top stating this document is final.

Is there a way to display that the document has been "marked as final" in the SharePoint Online Document library view? I was not able to find an out-of-the-box metadata column that displays this. Is there a SPFx extension available to do this?

*Note: I'm aware that I can add column on the document library called "Final" (Yes/No), this however is clunky as you would think the user marking the document as final would capture some metadata behind the scenes.*

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following. I did a quick test and seems to work fine.

Create a column of type 'Yes/No' and name the column '_MarkAsFinal' (exactly without quotes). Make the default value as 'No'. Upload a document and mark the document as final. The column should automatically be populated with 'Yes'. You can rename the column based on your requirement after the column has been created.

Comment: Thanks this is Impressive! I'd be curious to know how you figured this out?

Comment: This seems a bit flaky however. It worked for a document I had uploaded. But when I uploaded a new document and then set it to 'Marked as Final', then refreshed the page, it displays "No".

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint document life cycle is managed through the workflow. You can create a choice column with the value something like **Draft, In Progress, Final** , so once the document is submitted it will be in **Draft** mode, then if someone review the document it will be in **In Progress or Review** mode, and so on... finally we can make document status as **Final**

The above document life cycle can be managed through the workflow or Microsoft Flow or Nintex workflow.

You can refer to the below below example of document life cycle in SharePoint :

[Working Documents and Final Published Documents](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/working-documents-and-final-published-documents/m-p/97379)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm aware of workflows/power automate. I'm also aware that you can create a column on the library and manually set it or have it set by workflows. Workflows is overkill for my use case. I just want the document to be marked as final and have that appear in my library View.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks sssreddy for the solution with '_MarkAsFinal'. One more useful hint I found out after some troubles getting this solution to work: make sure Library Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Content Types -> 'Allow management of content types' is set to 'YES' and when you create the column UNCHECK 'Add to all content types'.